# Vertically Center Tumblr Layout

Tags: javascript, html, center, tumblr

I've been working on a new layout here: http://meaaas.tumblr.com/ it's a completely horrizontal layout, meaning it completely scrolls from side to side instead of up and down. Is there any possible way to use the current code i have to make it so that the posts would align to the vertical center instead of just being aligned to the top?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it would be to write a quick little Jquery script:

```
var contain = $('#posts').height();
$('.post').each(function(){
    var spacing = (contain - $(this).height());
    var top = spacing/2;
    $(this).css('margin-top', top);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Include this at the bottom of the page, before the 'BEGIN TUBMLR CODE' tag:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     var contain = $('#posts').height();
     $('.post').each(function(){
         var spacing = (contain - $(this).height());
         var top = spacing/2;
         $(this).css('margin-top', top);
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is assuming you just want each post in the ol aligned vertically. Now if you want that ol to be aligned vertically, you don't need the each and Nathaniel's suggestion about window.onresize is best.

Comment: i want each post in the OL to be aligned vertically.

Comment: Ah, okay, well, first, just looking at your page, you haven't defined JQuery anywhere.  Which means that some of your functions aren't actually working. In the head, include this link: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> . Don't include the semicolon, not sure why it's showing up. After that, you can include any scripts that begin with $

Answer (score 0):

This is something notoriously tricky to do. [This Article](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) has a few suggestions, each with Pros and Cons.

If you're willing to add some javascript, that might be the simplest thing to understand. Just write some code that checks the size of the window and calculates what the top-margin should be. You could also add a resize function so that the margin is recalculated when the window size is changed (use the `window.onresize` event)

**UPDATE** here's some very naive javascript:

```
function verticallyCenter(elementID){
    var windowheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById(elementID).style.marginTop = windowheight / 4;
}
```

Add that into a `<script>` block in the `<head>` of the page and then add `onload="verticallyCenter(elementID)"` to the `<body>` tag. You'll need to replace `elementID` with the ID of the div you want to center. You probably also want to account for the height of the content better than just using a quarter of the page height.

Comment: i would totally be willing to add javascript but i've never written any, i'm a rather big noob when it comes to that.

Comment: i must be doing something wrong because it doesn't seem to work, with or without the ' ' around the elementid.

Comment: it should just be the element ID in quotes: "posts" if you want to center the whole <ol> strip.